# the kernel in pryUp()

Tags: opencv, kernel

I was trying to use the function pryUp() in OpenCV.

In document it said "First, it upsamples the source image by injecting even zero rows and columns and then convolves the result with the same kernel as in pyrDown() multiplied by 4." in [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrup#pyrup).

My question is why it doesn't use the same kernel? Why multiplied by 4? I think it also works with the same kernel in pryDown().

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because injecting zero rows and columns to double the image area affects the renormalization of the kernel, so if it wasn't multiplied by 4 (i.e. doubled in each direction), then the overall result would suffer an unwanted reduction in intensity because the additional zeros would be averaged in the result.